# How to find if in an array of scores each score is equal to or lower than the one preceding it?

Tags: java

Under some set of scores the code "misbehave" and ending with false result. This occurs for example on this set of scores:

5, 4, 3, 2, 5

As long as the numbers decreasing everything is fine, but at the last step, where it's increasing again, the code fails to return the right answer.

Any help and explanation would be really appreciated.

**Task**
Given an array of scores, print 'true' if each score is equal to or lower than the one preceding it.
**Input Format**
The first line contains a single integer, n, denoting the size of the array. Each of the subsequent n lines contains a single integer denoting the value of the array at the next position.
**Constraint**
The length of the array will be 2 or more.
**Output**
Simply the word 'true' or 'false'.

**Input** 5   4 3 2 1 1 **Expected Output** true **Output** true
**Input** 5   4 3 2 1 2 **Expected Output** false **Output** true

Already tried multiple solutions by my own but I'm an absolutely beginner, all my attempts failed.

```
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
    int a = sc.nextInt();

    int[] array3 = new int[a];
    int m; int j = 1; int ctn=-1;

    //System.out.println("ctn= -1");
    for(int i=0; i<array3.length; i++){ 
        m = sc.nextInt();
        while(j<array3.length && array3[j] < m){
            j++;
        }          
            if(j == array3.length){    
                array3[i] = m;
                ctn++;
                j = 0;
                //System.out.println("ctn+1 m>j " + ctn);
            }else{
                array3[i] = m;
                j = 0;
                //System.out.println("ctn m<=j " + ctn);
            }
    }

    if(ctn != 0){
        System.out.println("false");
    }else{
        System.out.println("true");
    }
}
```

}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Edit:
I'm not entirely certain if you want each score to be equal to or lower than **all the scores** preceeding it (or) the **immediate score** preceding it.

If it's just the immediate score preceding it, then a simple loop with lookup to check with previous value would do, else refer to the below.

---

The easy way to do this would be to keep track of the lowest 'score' that you've encountered so far and use it for a check condition.

```
Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
int count= scan.nextInt();
int lowest = Integer.MAX_VALUE;
boolean flag = false;
for(int i=0;i<count;i++) {
    int current = scan.nextInt();
    if(lowest<current) {
        flag = true;
        break;
    } else if(current<lowest) {
        lowest = current;
    }
}
if(flag) {
    System.out.println("false");
} else {
    System.out.println("true");
}
```

Comment: Thx for the quick response. Just checked the code, it's working perfectly. Thank you very much for your help, I really appreciate it. Any suggestions how could I make my code to get the same results?

Comment: No probs. Tbh, I didn't really understand what you were trying to do in your code. Could you elaborate as to what you tried to do here?.

Comment: I tried to compare the "incoming" number to the last one in the array. As long as the number in the array greater or equal to the new number nothing happens by intention. If the number in the array lower to the new number than the code adds +1 to ctn. The problem is that in the example set of scores 5.4.3.2.5 after number 2 it increasing to 5 but it doesn't add +1 to count and because of this the output is not correct, it's true instead of false.

Answer (score 0):

Try the below code:

```
Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
int a = sc.nextInt();
int[] array3 = new int[a];
String res = "true" ;

for(int i=0; i<array3.length; i++){
    array3[i]= sc.nextInt();
    if(i>0 && array3[i-1] < array3[i]) res = "false";
}
System.out.print(res);
```

Additionally you can add a `break` inside `if` if you do not want to enter any more values once your condition is violated.

Comment: Thx for the quick response. Just checked the code, this is also works perfectly. It is funny how much time did I waste on this simple task, you guys sorted in a few minutes. Thx again.